# Alphanumberic output from ST_MakeLine

Tags: sql, postgresql, gis, postgis

I'm trying to convert lat/lon to linestring.  Basically, grouping the columns lat and lon, making a point, and creating a linestring.

Table:

```
+------------+----------+-----------+------------+---------+--------+
|  link_id   | seq_num  |    lat    |    lon     | z_coord | zlevel |
+------------+----------+-----------+------------+---------+--------+
| "16777220" | "0"      | "4129098" | "-7192948" |         |      0 |
| "16777220" | "999999" | "4129134" | "-7192950" |         |      0 |
| "16777222" | "0"      | "4128989" | "-7193030" |         |      0 |
| "16777222" | "1"      | "4128975" | "-7193016" |         |      0 |
| "16777222" | "2"      | "4128940" | "-7193001" |         |      0 |
| "16777222" | "3"      | "4128917" | "-7192998" |         |      0 |
| "16777222" | "4"      | "4128911" | "-7193002" |         |      0 |
+------------+----------+-----------+------------+---------+--------+
```

My code:

```
select link_id, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint((lon::double precision / 100000), (lat::double precision / 100000))),4326) as geometry
from public.rdf_link_geometry
group by link_id
limit 50
```

geometry output column example:
"0102000020E6100000020000004F92AE997CFB51C021E527D53EA54440736891ED7CFB51C021020EA14AA54440"

^^ What is this?  how did it get formatted in such a way?  I expected a linestring, something like

```
geometry
7.123 50.123,7.321 50.321
7.321 50.321,7.321 50.321
```

Data format for link_id is bingint, and for geometry it says geometry

SOLUTION:

```
select link_id, ST_AsText(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(
(lon::double precision / 100000), (lat::double precision / 100000))),4326)) as geometry
from public.rdf_link_geometry
group by link_id
limit 50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is a `geometry`, which you can display as text using `st_asText`

```
select st_asText('0102000020E6100000020000004F92AE997CFB51C021E527D53EA54440736891ED7CFB51C021020EA14AA54440');
                    st_astext
--------------------------------------------------
 LINESTRING(-71.92948 41.29098,-71.9295 41.29134)
```

That being said, should you have more than 2 points, you could order them to create a meaningful line:

```
select st_makeline(geom ORDER BY seqID) from tbl;
```

Comment: Yes I have more than 2 points one some (many) records...it was just an example of the formatting.  This solution works!  Thanks so much!